# How to add Entry control dynamically and retrieve it's value?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used below code to generate entry control dynamically.

```
Entry myEntry = new Entry();
myEntry.Placeholder = "My Entry Text Here";
myEntry.Text = "My Entry Text";`
```

Now, i want to fetch it's value from code behind, so how can i achieve that.

I have also found the below way to find the control by Name(x:Name) but i am unable to set Name(x:Name) Property of Entry Control when i add it from code behind.

```
Entry getMyEntryText = this.FindByName<Entry>("Control Name");
```

So is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: maybe its better to explain what you are trying to achieve, doesn't seem like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are still a bigenner and have a lot to learn from , so my advice to you is to watch more tutorials and read more about xamarin.forms .

The first peice of code is already written in the code behind, the term ***code behind*** refers to the code that decides how the page would look like and not written in Xaml abd also resides in a partial class that. So if you do not have Xaml file you do not have a code behind.

The second peice of code is not Xamarin.Forms.

```
Entry getMyEntryText = this.FindByName<Entry>("Control Name");
```

It is Xamarin.Android which if you have a layout written in axml. Then you can fitch a control from it with this way

So it is clearly that you need to put more effort and spend more time to get all your answers.

Comment: so you are commenting after 2 years now ? 
I did not know that there is FindByName not because i am not educated, but because simple no one needs it in general.  if you have a xaml file then you just use `x:name=""`which can be referred to  in the code behind.  If you do not have a xaml file then there is no code behind . so my advice for you is to read the question and the answer before start attacking :) anyway we all can get wrong .